# Audio file still loops after setting setOnCompletionListener android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I have added the setOnCompletionListener into my code but still, the audio file kept on looping after it is finished (Audio File retrieved from firebase storage URL).....I am not too sure what the problem is as the code I added seems pretty fine...

Here is the code for the activity that allow users to play audio file

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var imageViewClass: ImageView
private lateinit var textViewClassName: TextView
private lateinit var textViewClassDes: TextView
private lateinit var textViewClassContent: TextView
private var stop:Boolean = false
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

    val btnPlay: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)
    val btnStop: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnStop)


    imageViewClass = findViewById(R.id.imageViewClassImage)
    textViewClassName = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassName)
    textViewClassDes = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassDescription)
    textViewClassContent = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassContent)


    val classImage = intent.getStringExtra("class_image")
    val className = intent.getStringExtra("class_name")
    val classDes = intent.getStringExtra("class_des")
    val classContent = intent.getStringExtra("class_content")
    val classAudio = intent.getStringExtra("class_audio")

    Glide.with(this)
        .load(classImage)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageViewClass)
    textViewClassName.text = className
    textViewClassDes.text = classDes
    textViewClassDes.text = classDes!!.replace("\\n", "\n")
    textViewClassContent.text = classContent
    textViewClassContent.text = classContent!!.replace("\\n", "\n")

    btnPlay.isEnabled = true
    btnStop.isEnabled = false

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@DetailActivity, Uri.parse(classAudio))
                mediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
                btnStop.isEnabled = true
                btnPlay.isEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Audio Starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
            }
        }
    })

    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        btnPlay.isEnabled = true
        btnStop.isEnabled = false
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.reset()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if(mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying){
                stop = false
                mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                mediaPlayer!!.reset()
                mediaPlayer!!.release()
                mediaPlayer = null
                btnPlay.isEnabled = true
                btnStop.isEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Audio Stops",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })
}

override fun onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy()
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.reset()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Hi I have edited the tag, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You don't create media player during fragment creation. So during call:

```kotlin
mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        btnPlay.isEnabled = true
        btnStop.isEnabled = false
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.reset()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

mediaPlayer is always null. Therefore the listener is never set.

Just move this code to the onClick method after mediaPlayer is being created

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I had followed your steps but it still doesn't seem to be working as it was intended to be...

Comment: @CaesarHo Have you tried setting up breakpoint and debugging it?